# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path debian

Tags: java, rxtx

I trying to use rxtx serial communication library on debian  and I have added librxtx.so into native library path but still this exception is occurred .

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
    at com.vxoom.qit.basic.Log4jInit.startPrinterThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.vxoom.qit.basic.Log4jInit.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:39)
    atwinstone.ServletConfiguration.ensureInitialization(ServletConfiguration.java:183)
    at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:918)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:131)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:73)
    at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:85)
    at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:196)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:391)
```

Comment: Please some one help me ....

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to copy the link to the library to where the jvm can see it like so:

```
cp '/usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so' '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386'
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory where you have the `.so` file.

Let the directory in which you have the  `.so` file is `/home/abc`

Use this command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"/home/abc"
```

In java load the .so in the following manner..

```
System.loadLibraryPath("rxtxSerial");
```

To set it permanently you have to put the same line in `.profile` file
which will be in your home directory.

[you can refer to this guide](http://www.think-techie.com/2009/08/java-native-interface-jni.html)

Comment: can you tell what are you passing in System.loadLibrary("")
and what is the exact name of the library.

Comment: I m adding library from eclipse build path configuration and library name is librxtxSerail.so

Comment: System.loadLibraryPath("rxtxSerial");

Answer (score 0):

I will copy and paste the rxtx INSTALL help

```
Solution 1: move the file to a place that works

     $ mv /usr/local/lib/librxtxSerial.* /usr/local/java/jre/lib/i386/

Solution 2: add the location of librxtxSerial to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

     $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/

Solution 3: pass the location in on the command line

     $ java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/ ...
```

Source

http://rxtx.qbang.org/pub/rxtx/rxtx-2.1-7pre17/INSTALL

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the rxtxSerial.dll into the jreXX/bin folder